# Returning a dictionary of ndarray causes memory leaks using boost python

Tags: python, c++, opencv, boost, memory-leaks

I am writing a c++ module for python. It takes a image, does some processing and returns a dictionary of images. I am having memory leaks which I can't figure out why..

I use [opencv-ndarray-conversion](https://github.com/yati-sagade/opencv-ndarray-conversion) to convert between `cv::Mat` and `numpy.ndarray`

I use [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/) to convert c++ code to python module.

I use the following python code to test the c++ module, while running `htop` to check the memory usage.

```
import cv2
import this_cpp_module

for i in xrange(100000):
    img = cv2.imread('a_640x480x3_image.png')
    ret = this_cpp_module.func(img)
    #this 'func' is mapping to one of the following c++ functions, using Boost.Python:
    #    func1, func2 or func3.
```

1, Converting the image does not cause memory leaks

```
using namespace boost::python;
PyObject * func1(PyObject *image)
{
    NDArrayConverter cvt;
    cv::Mat mat;
    mat = cvt.toMat(image);
    PyObject* ret = cvt.toNDArray(mat);
    return ret;
}
```

2, Constructing a dictionary and putting the image into it do not cause memory leaks

```
using namespace boost::python;
dict func2(PyObject *image)
{
    dict pyDict;    
    object objImage(handle<>(borrowed(image)));
    pyDict[std::string("key")] = objImage;    
    return pyDict;
}
```

3, But combining them causes the memory leaks (around 1MB per loop)

```
dict func3(PyObject *image)
{
    return func2(func1(image));
}
```

I cannot figure it out. Everything seems to be correct to me but combining them together just causes this problem.

Comment: Could you add source for `func`, that may be related to the memory leak.

Comment: @AndrewJohnson `func` is mapping to one of the c++ functions: `func1`, `func2` or `func3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leak is a result of `func3()` never properly disposing the temporary owned reference returned by `func1()`.  To resolve this, `func3()` needs to do one of the following:

- Explicitly invoke [`Py_DECREF()`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/refcounting.html#Py_XDECREF) on the owned reference returned from `func1()` before returning from `func3()`.
- Manage the value returned by `func1()` with a [`boost::python::handle`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/handle.html#handle-spec), as it will decrement the object's reference count when the `handle` is destroyed.

For example, `func3()` could be written as:

```
boost::python::dict func3(PyObject* image)
{
  // func1() returns an owned reference, so create a handle to keep the
  // object alive for at least as long as the handle remains alive.  The
  // handle will properly dispose of the reference.
  boost::python::handle<> handle(func1(image));
  return func2(handle.get());
}
```

For details on the original problem, when `func1()` returns, the returned object has a [reference count of `1`](https://github.com/yati-sagade/opencv-ndarray-conversion/blob/6c8b873892b836de18d4c30410038ad721a2e0ab/conversion.cpp#L229).  Upon returning from `func2()` and `func3()`, the object has a reference count of `2`.  When the `dict` returned from `func3()` is destroyed, the object initially returned from `func1()` will have its reference count decremented by `1`, resulting in the leaked object having a reference count of `1`.

---

Here is a complete minimal example based on the original code:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

PyObject* func1(PyObject*)
{
  return PyList_New(0);
}

boost::python::dict func2(PyObject* obj)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::dict dict;
  python::handle<> handle(python::borrowed(obj));
  dict[std::string("key")] = python::object(handle);
  return dict;
}

boost::python::dict func3(PyObject* obj)
{
  // Fails to properly dispose of the owned reference returned by func1(),
  // resulting in a leak.
  return func2(func1(obj));
}

boost::python::dict func4(PyObject* obj)
{
  // func1() returns an owned reference, so create a handle to keep the
  // object alive for at least as long as the handle remains alive.  The
  // handle will properly dispose of the reference.
  boost::python::handle<> handle(func1(obj));
  return func2(handle.get());
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::def("func1", &func1);
  python::def("func2", &func2);
  python::def("func3", &func3);
  python::def("func4", &func4);
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> from sys import getrefcount
>>> import example
>>> x = example.func1(None)
>>> assert(2 == getrefcount(x)) # refs: x and getrefcount
>>> d = example.func2(x)
>>> assert(3 == getrefcount(x)) # refs: x, d["key"], and getrefcount
>>> d = None
>>> assert(2 == getrefcount(x)) # refs: x and getrefcount
>>> d = example.func3(None)
>>> x = d["key"]
>>> assert(4 == getrefcount(x)) # refs: x, d["key"], getrefcount, and one leak
>>> d = None
>>> assert(3 == getrefcount(x)) # refs: x, getrefcount, and one leak
>>> d = example.func4(None)
>>> x = d["key"]
>>> assert(3 == getrefcount(x)) # refs: x, d["key"], and getrefcount
>>> d = None
>>> assert(2 == getrefcount(x)) # refs: x and getrefcount
```