# How to return a list of dicts from C++ to python using boost.python without leaking memory?

Tags: python, c++, boost, memory-leaks, boost-python

I have some code in C++ and I want to call it from Python. The C++ code returns lists of dicts to the python code. I use boost.python to achieve this, in the following manner:

```
struct MyStruct { 
    int foo;
};

class MyClass 
{  
public:
    std::vector<MyStruct> get_stuff();
};

struct MyStructConverter
{
    static PyObject* convert(const std::vector<MyStruct>& v)
    {
        boost::python::list ret;
        for (auto c : v) {
            boost::python::dict *r = new boost::python::dict();   
            (*r)["foo"] = c.foo;
            ret.append(boost::python::object(*r));
         }
        return boost::python::incref(ret.ptr());
    }
};


/** Interface between C++ and Python
 */
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(glue)
{
    boost::python::to_python_converter<std::vector<MyStruct>, MyStructConverter>();

    class_<MyClass, boost::noncopyable>("MyClass")
        .def("get_stuff", &MyClass::get_stuff);
}
```

This works to the extent that I can pass data from C++ to python. However, when used as follows:

```
# test.py
x = MyClass()
while True:
    u = x.get_stuff()
    # do something with u
```

it leaks memory (i.e. the VSZ of the python process keeps growing until the whole system grinds to a halt).

What am I doing wrong? How can I avoid this?

Comment: Can you check whether this answer helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875357/returning-a-dictionary-of-ndarray-causes-memory-leaks-using-boost-python

Comment: It does seem quite relevant, but I'm still struggling to see how I could use it here.